# I am trying to wrap my head around NDP

Tags: routing, ipv6, layer2, layer3, ndp

[image]

I know before PC10 can ping PC11 it will use IPv6 Neighbor Discovery to resolve the Destination MAC address for layer 2 header.
But what would the DEST MAC ADDR be and what topics can I learn this

Answer (score 2):

> I know before PC10 can ping PC11 it will use IPv6 Neighbor Discovery
> to resolve the Destination MAC address for layer 2 header.

When PC10 wants to send something to PC11, it already knows that PC11 is on a different network, so it does *not* try to find the layer-2 address of PC11. The IPv6 packet will be encapsulated in a layer-2 frame using the gateway layer-2 address it received from the router RAs.

The router will strip off the layer-2 frame to route the IPv6 packet to the next interface, where it will build a new layer-2 frame for the new network to encapsulate the IPv6 packet.

Comment: what would the DEST MAC ADDR be

Comment: Please read my answer: "_The IPv6 packet will be encapsulated in a layer-2 frame using the gateway layer-2 address it received from the router RAs._"

Comment: As far as PC10 is concerned, PC 11 may be on the moon or another galaxy as it will never know its MAC address and it does not care what it is. MAC addresses are only significant on the Local Network. Once traffic leaves the local network, the gateway and any other routing hops in the path take over local interface and layer 2 resolution/lookups etc.